# shopping cart total price in nested dict python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to calculate the total price in my shopping cart with the code below, but I am unable to iterate through the price in my items dict. Something is missing there. Also, if the for loop can be fixed, is there any way to iterate using comprehensions?

```
class ShoppingCart(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.item = None
        self.quantity = None
        self.price = None
        self.items = {}
    def add(self, item, price, quantity):

        if item in self.items:
            previous_quantity = self.items[item]['quantity']
            previous_price = self.items[item]['price']

            self.items[item] = {'quantity': previous_quantity +   quantity,
                                'price': previous_price + price}
        else:
            self.items[item] = {'quantity':quantity,
                           'price':price}

    def total_items_in_cart(self):
         print(len(self.items))

    def total_items_price_in_cart(self):
         print(sum([price
                 for price in self.items.values()]))

sc = ShoppingCart()
sc.add('book', 30, 1)
# sc.add('book', 132, 1)

sc.add('toothbrush', 4, 10)
# sc.add('toothbrush', 5, 20)

# sc.total_items_in_cart()

cart_price_total = []
for item, value in sc.items.items():
    print("\n{}".format(item))
    for price,qty in value.items():
        print("{} :{}".format(price, qty))
        cart_price_total.append(qty)

print(cart_price_total) # this does not print what I want...
```

Is there a way to use comprehensions to get the total value in my cart?

EDIT:

```
I added the data using a tuple, and it seems simple now. Cannot figure out why...

class ShoppingCart(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.item = None
        self.quantity = None
        self.price = None
        self.items = {}
    def add(self, item, price, quantity):
        if item in self.items:
            previous_quantity = self.items[item]['quantity']
            previous_price = self.items[item]['price']
            self.items[item] = (previous_quantity+quantity, previous_price+price)
        else:
            self.items[item] = (price, quantity)

    def total_items_in_cart(self):
         return(len(self.items))

    def total_items_price_in_cart(self):
         return(sum([price
                 for price, quantity in self.items.values()]))

sc = ShoppingCart()
sc.add('book', 30, 1)
sc.add('toothbrush', 4, 10)
print(sc.total_items_in_cart())
print(sc.total_items_price_in_cart())
```

Comment: you mean `total_items_price_in_cart()` does not work?

Comment: And why do you use `print` instead of `return` in your methods?

Comment: @IvanVinogradov, yes I agree. I should've used return

Comment: Furthermore — `self.quantity`, `self.item` and `self.price` are never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just define a new instance variable such as `_total_price` and keep it updated as you add items:

```
class ShoppingCart(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.item = None
        self.quantity = None
        self.price = None
        self.items = {}
        self._total_price = 0

    def add(self, item, price, quantity):
        if item in self.items:
            previous_quantity = self.items[item]['quantity']
            previous_price = self.items[item]['price']
            self.items[item] = {'quantity': previous_quantity + quantity,
                                'price': previous_price + price}
        else:
            self.items[item] = {'quantity':quantity, 'price':price}
        self._total_price += price * quantity

    @property
    def total_items_in_cart(self):
        return len(self.items) # better return a value instead of printing it

    @property
    def total_items_price_in_cart(self):
        return self._total_price

sc = ShoppingCart()
sc.add('book', 30, 1)
# sc.add('book', 132, 1)

sc.add('toothbrush', 4, 10)
# sc.add('toothbrush', 5, 20)

print(sc.total_items_in_cart)
print(sc.total_items_price_in_cart)
```

Of course you will need to deal with the case when user wants to remove an item from the cart.

Comment: Thanks. This is good as well.. If I change the add() method to assign a tuple, I see some difference... why is that?
    def add(self, item, price, quantity):
        self.items[item] = (price, quantity)

    def total_items_in_cart(self):
         print(len(self.items))

    def total_items_price_in_cart(self):
         print(sum([price*quantity
                 for price, quantity in self.items.values()]))

Answer (score 1):

Change your `total_items_price_in_cart` function to this:

```
def total_items_price_in_cart(self):
    items_prices = {k: v['price'] * v['quantity'] for (k, v) in self.items.items()}
    # items_prices == {'book': 30, 'toothbrush': 40}
    return sum(items_prices.values())
```

Output with input data in question:

> `70`

Comment: Thanks. Did I complicate my code? is this the best approach?

Comment: Well, at least it’s not perfect. And remember that design heavily depends on your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ShoppingCart` Class have price attribute, but you don't use it.
You should only use your `self.items = {}`, you don't use `self.item`, `self.quantity` and `self.price`.

But, for your problem here the solution:

```
print(cart_price_total) # this does not print what I want...
```

Yeah but seems like your cart_price_total doesn't contened you're items values... But values AND items count.

Try this:

```
print(sum([sc.items[x]['price']*sc.items[x]['quantity'] for x in sc.items]))
```